# Express server serves my static files but does not handle requests to my API. What is happening?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I built a small app on top of a company's API. I created my own API to interact with their's. My app uses React-Create-App to scaffold, with Redux, and the server is Experss/Node.js. It works totally fine on localhost but when I deploy it on Heroku, it serves the bundle but doesn't hand any user http requests to the server. It returns a 404 not found. Heroku gives no errors in their logs.

My post install script runs the build, which bundles the app. I have set environment port variable in the heroku dashboard as well.

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "event.me",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
    "engines":{
    "node": "7.2.1",
    "npm": "3.10.10"  
  },  
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-progressbar.js": "^0.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.18.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node server/server.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  }
}
```

server.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', routes);
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port}`));
```

routes.js

```js
const routes = require('express').Router();
const users = require('./controllers/users.js');
const events = require('./controllers/events.js');

routes.post('/sigin', users.signin);
routes.post('/signup', users.signup);
routes.get('/events', events.getAll);
routes.post('/events', events.attendEvent);
routes.delete('/events', events.flakeEvent);
routes.patch('/events', events.updateEvent);
routes.delete('/singleevent', events.deleteEvent);
routes.post('/createevent', events.createEvent);

module.exports = routes;
```

Comment: Are you saying that a post request to `/api/sigin` does not call `users.signin`?  Also, notice that `sigin` is probably misspelled in your route definition.

Comment: That was luckily misspelled in two different places, so it didn't cause a problem. But thanks for pointing it out. I get this error in the browser `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I cannot tell if it gets called or not based on the heroku logs, nor do I know how I can determine that.

Comment: What is the exact URL that gets the 404?

Comment: `https://<name of app>.herokuapp.com/api/sigin Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` It's https, does that make a difference?

Comment: And, are you doing a POST to that URL?  You only have a route registered for POST, not for GET.

Comment: Your Express code is starting an http server, NOT an https server so your express server isn't listening for https connections unless heroku is proxying an https connection for you and then connecting to you with http.

Comment: Yes, only a post to that route.

Comment: I was under the impression heroku did proxy an https connection. Could be wrong.

Comment: Did you try the same URL with http just as a test?

Comment: @jfriend00 same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Create React App, one of the things you must do if you want Webpack to be used as proxy when calling your API is to set in your `package.json`:

```
...
"proxy": "http://localhost:3030",
...
```

Thus you use Webpack included in Create React App to proxy all the calls to your API and do not need an extra server.
For Heroku deployment you need to change localhost for Heroku URL and 3030 for your established port in Express server (process.env.PORT).
That's where I think the problem lies.

Also, you have to route your non API petitions to your index.html.
Add this to your `server.js`.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const way = path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html');
    res.sendFile(way);
  });
```

Comment: So it would be something like `"proxy": "https://<name of app>.herokuapp.com:3030"`

Comment: Yes, though I am not sure if the protocol needs another kind of handling (being server-side in Express or at Heroku configuration). Never set a https React app.

Comment: Heroku configures it to https automatically.

Comment: New error at least: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Update your question with all the info needed to be able to help you, please.